# Install ubuntu inside windows comes out in ubuntu CD instead of install parallelly

Tags: windows, system-installation

here's the problem:

I downloaded the ubuntu (12.04 lts) image installer and burnt it on a CD. When I put it and restarted windows, instead of the "Install ubuntu alongside windows" option shown in ubuntu instructions, came a "install ubuntu inside windows" (or something similar). I would like to know how I can install it parallelly to windows, so that later I can uninstall windows.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to start Windows first (so take the CD out, then boot to Windows and put it in), then run the installer from within Windows.

Comment: Well, thank you for answering, thou I'm not sure if this comment will go like yours, or as a main comment. The thing is that I did as you said (I have windows vista as the other operative system), and when I put the CD once windows had shown the desktop, it showed the option run "wubi", and that's exactly what I wouldn't like...because as I understan wubi is an installer for ubuntu "inside" windows, and I want it alongside windows.

Comment: Oh I understand you now (not sure why I didn't before).

Simply start up your system with the CD and you should be able to install alongside Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, everything I needed was an available logical partition. I think that says it all, but the thing was that I was trying to install ubuntu without free space on my disks, so I decided to emtpy a drive, and then, with the windows CD installer (I don't know how to do it with the ubuntu CD installer) I deleted one partition. When I rebooted and inserted the ubuntu CD installer, it said: "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Vista".